# npm on Mac OS installs scripts that won't run

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I have npm V3.10.3 installed and am trying to use it to install a package as follows:

```
sudo npm install markdown-to-html -g
```

It looks like it downloads and installs everything, but the script files all have DOS-like line terminators (CR/LF) and the bash shell can't deal with it.  As a result:

```
$ markdown README.md 
-bash: /usr/local/bin/markdown: node^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The script starts with:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/markdown
#!node
// Converts a markdown file into an HTML file, writing it to stdout.
//
```

It would seem that the ^M is causing bash not to find node, which is installed.  Is there any way to fix this in a systemic way?  I really don't want to process the files manually after the install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module you are using looks like it may be abandonware because it's apparently been like this for a long time. The best solution might be to find another markdown processor, but if you really want to use this one, here's one workaround:

- Open the executable in the `vi` editor:
  `` sudo vi `which markdown` ``

  (You typically only need `sudo` in that command if you used `sudo` to install the module in the first place. You indicate above that you did that but for others, you likely can and should leave the `sudo` off if you didn't need it to install the module in the first place.)
- Change all the line endings to UNIX line endings by typing `:set ff=unix` and pressing return
- Save your changes and exit the editor by typing `:wq` and pressing return

The `markdown` command should now be usable.

Comment: so in summary the problem is with the package.  I had thought that perhaps the npm package I am using somehow was grabbing the wrong version or variation of it.    I'll use your workaround for now but also look for another better package.